# Understanding marginalization of probabilities in more complex than the standard situation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Marginalization of the joint distribution of two (discrete) events $A$ and $B$ is given by $$P(A)= \sum_B P(A,B) = \sum_B P(A\mid B)P(B).$$

While I understand and recognize this standard case, I often encounter derivations in which marginalization is used differently. Is there something more to say than the above on rules for marginalization? In the specific case I am thinking about I have $$ \sum_C P(B\mid A,C)P(C\mid A)P(A) = P(B\mid A) P(A).$$ This does not resemble the definition above at all, and I have difficulties seeing why this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second version does resemble the first version if you recall that in a sense all probabilities are conditional. In the first marginalization that you presented,
$$
P(A)= \sum_B P(A,B) = \sum_B P(A\mid B)P(B),
$$
the events $A$ and $B$ are subsets of some probability space (or "sample space" or "universe"), which let us call $\Omega.$ So you have $P(\Omega)=1$ and
$$
P(A\mid\Omega)= \sum_B P(A,B\mid\Omega)P(\Omega) = \sum_B P(A\mid B,\Omega)P(B\mid\Omega)P(\Omega),
$$
and it's still the same thing, but it looks just like your second marginalization.